# Which nodes of the Collada .DAE are most relevant for game object & character use?

Tags: 3d, game-engine, mesh, collada, skeletal-mesh

I was looking to choose an intermediary format that can get from 3D modeling software to my internally used format. **Collada `.DAE`** seems to be good as it can export animation too and it's XML. Kind of bloated but easy to parse.

Before being a wannabe game developer, my expertise is in reusable code writing, libraries, APIs and such. **So my first impulse was to go an implement a FULL parser of the Collada format** given the fact that I'm not 100% what I need or will need to extract from it.

As it seems Collada is trying to be everything and the kitchen sink, **there's definitely stuff in there I don't think I need to be concerned about.** So, sanity prevailed and decided to come here and ask the experienced people **what are the important nodes for game characters and objects in the `.DAE` file? Or is there another format considered friendlier by game devs that can export animations too?**

I've **figured out the following are important**:

- geometries *(mesh + triangles)*
- materials + images
- animations + controllers
- visual scenes + scene

**What else am I missing from the top-level node list?** I don't think `/lights` are important as I deal with that in code. I just need to import meshes + textures + animations. At least for now, as I'm just starting out in D3D programming.

For a non-animated object I can get away with a `.OBJ` file but for a character with animation, I really don't think `.OBJ` supports them.

> So the question is: **Which DAE nodes are relevant to game objects and animated characters?**... *and if someone experienced consuming this format could provide a few words describing them, in a more game-friendly way then that specification... would be great!* Or should I use another intermediary format but `.DAE`?

**PS**: *As I'm in a learning frenzy right now, I'm not interested to use external tools. I will write my own parser, exporter, format... everything. :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collada is the way to go for exporting animations IMO. I am kinda doing the similar thing these days and I found [this](http://tinyurl.com/o6zxqlt) a little helpful.

Comment: **That is one GOOD tutorial.** Thank you! I've already done the parser structure with `IXmliteReader` and this answer came just at the right time, when I was deciding which nodes to handle first.

Comment: You're welcome :) and I hope you didn't miss part-2 of the tutorial: http://tinyurl.com/l3vjb7w